# Remove note added by knitr in R markdown document

Tags: r, knitr

I have knitted an `html` document in `R`. The output is good; it's just that at the very end I see this note:

```
Note that the echo = FALSE parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot
```

How can I remove this note from showing in the knitted document?

Comment: Can you please post your entire document? This looks like it may be in there as text, not generated by Rmarkdown. It certainly doesn't produce that note on my version of Rmarkdown (version 2.9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear in my version of Rmarkdown running the test document below:

````
---
title: R Markdown
output: html_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots:

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

So I think there are two posibilities.

1. You accidentally added it (perhaps by copying [this template](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/rmarkdown.html#r-markdown)), or
2. It was removed in a previous version, as the latest version of Rmarkdown (2.9) does not produce this warning.

I suspect it's case 1, as I've never seen this output automatically inserted before.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this text was in there in the template while creating an empty `.rmd` document.